# Cosa significa "svettare" in questa frase?

Tags: word-meaning, verbs

Nel romanzo *Una questione privata* di Beppe Fenoglio ho letto:

> Ecco i quattro ciliegi che fiancheggiavano il vialetto oltre il cancello appena accostato, ecco i due faggi
> che **svettavano** di molto oltre il tetto scuro e lucido.

La mia domanda è sul senso del verbo "svettare" in questa frase. Cercando il vocabolo nel [vocabolario Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/svettare/), tenendo conto che si tratta di alberi ma che si parla anche del tetto di una casa, a me sembra che possa avere questi due significati:

> **2.a.** letter. Di alberi, agitare la vetta: *i cipressi di sotto la Rocca svettavano, i lecci di sotto il castello tumultuavano* (D’Annunzio).
>
> **2.c.** Emergere tra altre cose o persone: *la ragazza, per la sua inusuale altezza, svettava tra le altre compagne*; anche in senso fig.: *è uno studente che svetta per ingegno*.

Mi sapreste spiegare a quale di queste due accezioni si riferisce la frase sopra citata? Cioè, i faggi agitavano la vetta oltre il tetto della casa oppure i faggi oltrepassavano di molto il tetto della casa?

Comment: Secondo me la seconda.

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti:  E forse la ragione è che nella frase appare "di molto oltre il tetto" e quindi si sta comparando la vetta dei faggi con il tetto della casa?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Credo sia la seconda delle accezioni confrontate, scartando la prima che, se il verbo "svettare" non fosse seguito da "di molto oltre il tetto scuro e lucido", probabilmente avrebbe potuto riferirsi all'ampiezza delle oscillazioni descritte dalle punte degli alberi agitate dal vento. Un altro [significato](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/svettare/) che ben descrive il senso di *svettare* nella frase citata è, a mio avviso,

> b. **Elevarsi, slanciarsi con la vetta contro uno sfondo di cielo**: *il campanile svettava nel cielo azzurro; montagne che svettano superbe*,

in cui il verbo è utilizzato come [sinonimo](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/svettare_(Sinonimi-e-Contrari)/) di:

> ergersi, innalzarsi, spiccare, stagliarsi, torreggiare.

Answer (score 0):

Gli alberi superavano di molto in altezza il tetto della casa. Era distinguibile dunque, una notevole differenza di altezza.